# WPF MultiBinding Converter Object Type

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding, relativesource

I have bound the `Checked` event of a checkbox to a method.  I am also passing two Command Parameters to that method through a converter (implementing `IMultiValueConverter`).  In the code below, the two `CommandParameter` bindings are of type `bool` and type `string` respectively.

```
<CheckBox Name="cbTopLeftHeader" Content="Top Left Header"> 
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding IncludeCheckedCommand}">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingConverter}" ConverterParameter="IncludeChecked">
                            <Binding ElementName="cbTopLeftHeader" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource TopLeft}"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                </i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

Why is it that if I replace the line:

```
<Binding ElementName="cbTopLeftHeader" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
```

With:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
```

In my converter the IsChecked parameter changes from type `bool` to type `DependencyProperty` (`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`)?

How can I achieve passing the `Checked` property without having the element bind to itself by name?

Comment: You are not binding the CommandParamter property of the CheckBox (as e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7617375/1136211)), hence `RelativeSource Self` is not the CheckBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid the interaction trigger and use the `Command` and `CommandParameter` properties of the `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox Name="cbTopLeftHeader" Content="Top Left Header" Command="{Binding IncludeCheckedCommand}">
    <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingConverter}" ConverterParameter="IncludeChecked">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsChecked"/>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource TopLeft}"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
</CheckBox>
```

Or stick with your current approach of binding to the `CheckBox` using `ElementName`. `{RelativeSource Self}` of an `InvokeCommandAction` is not a `CheckBox`.

Comment: Thank you mm8.  I did not realize (although seems obvious now) that the command for the checkbox by default is the `Checked` event.  Your answer and Clemens comment above answer my questions.